# Simple hello packet

Tags: network, clients, python, protocol, rlp

I am trying to generate a simple hello packet for handshaking with a remote Ethereum client using the encode method from the rlp library.

```
from rlp import encode

hello = bytearray(encode([0x00, 4, "cVersion", [["eth", 63], ["eth", 62], ["eth", 61]], myIntegerPortNumberHere, "0c00000d0a00051bb4b8f983c142eecf7d43e65c69b23cdbc908ddcd0cdc786b"]))
```

Could you tell me if this format complies with the specified protocol? Or, if it is broken, could you show me an example encoding for hello packet in Python.

Thanks!